# compare different keys in two lists of dictionary in python

Tags: python

I'am trying to compare 2 lists of dictionary to replace equal values. for example:

```
d1 = [{'a': 'hello', 'b':'world','c':'this','d':'is'},{'a':'ddd' ,'b': 'www','c':'hah','d':'tt'},.....]
d2 = [{'Q': 'hello', 'H':'target_word','K':'that','N':'was'},{'Q':'world' ,'H': 'target_word','K':'hah','N':'txt'},.....]
```

Can someone tell me how can I compare the keys ('a','b') in d1 with 'Q' in d2 if they have the same value then it must replace 'a's and 'b's value in d1 to 'H's value in d2 which is 'target_word'

this one of my attempts:

```
for i in d1:
   for j in d2:
    for k in i.keys():
        for k1 in j.keys():
            if j[k1] == i[k]:
                i[k] = j ['H']
                list.append(i[k])
```

Comment: What should your output be? You can just get the common keys, and do the comparision only on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look?

```
d1 = [{'a': 'hello', 'b':'world','c':'this','d':'is'},{'a':'ddd' ,'b': 'www','c':'hah','d':'tt'}]
d2 = [{'Q': 'hello', 'H':'target_word','K':'that','N':'was'},{'Q':'world' ,'H': 'target_word','K':'hah','N':'txt'}]

for input in d1:
    for queries in d2:
        for val in ("a", "b"):
            if input[val] == queries["Q"]:
                input[val] = queries["H"]
```

Output:

```
>>> d1
[{'a': 'target_word', 'c': 'this', 'b': 'target_word', 'd': 'is'}, {'a': 'ddd', 'c': 'hah', 'b': 'www', 'd': 'tt'}]
```